# Mobile Layout not taking 100% width

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Please help I cannot figure out how to make table container take 100% width.
I'm previewing HTML in phone with resolution 375px as width but there's seems to be white space area in the right side. I already tried changing min-width to 375px, changing table-layout to auto and width: 100% [image]

For some reason I cannot add code even in Javascript/HTML/CSS snippet, keeps getting my content contains mostly code. 
But here's the link to HTML code -

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">

<head></head>

<body class="clean-body" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;background-color: #F5F5F5;">
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport">
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        ol > li,
        ul > li,
        p,
        span,
        h1,
        h2,
        h3,
        h4,
        h5,
        h6,
        h7 {
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        
        table,
        td,
        tr {
            vertical-align: top;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        
        * {
            line-height: inherit;
        }
        
        a[x-apple-data-detectors=true] {
            color: inherit !important;
            text-decoration: none !important;
        }
    </style>
    <style id="media-query" type="text/css">
        @media (max-width: 670px) {
            #content_con {
                padding-left: 20px;
            }
            .block-grid,
            .col {
                min-width: 375px !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                display: block !important;
            }
            .block-grid {
                width: 100% !important;
            }
            .col {
                width: 100% !important;
            }
            .col>div {
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
            img.fullwidth,
            img.fullwidthOnMobile {
                max-width: 100% !important;
            }
            .no-stack .col {
                min-width: 0 !important;
                display: table-cell !important;
            }
            .no-stack.two-up .col {
                width: 50% !important;
            }
            .no-stack .col.num4 {
                width: 33% !important;
            }
            .no-stack .col.num8 {
                width: 66% !important;
            }
            .no-stack .col.num4 {
                width: 33% !important;
            }
            .no-stack .col.num3 {
                width: 25% !important;
            }
            .no-stack .col.num6 {
                width: 50% !important;
            }
            .no-stack .col.num9 {
                width: 75% !important;
            }
            .video-block {
                max-width: none !important;
            }
            .mobile_hide {
                min-height: 0px;
                max-height: 0px;
                max-width: 0px;
                display: none;
                overflow: hidden;
                font-size: 0px;
            }
            .desktop_hide {
                display: block !important;
                max-height: none !important;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <table bgcolor="#F5F5F5" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="nl-container" role="presentation" style="table-layout: fixed;vertical-align: top;min-width: 380px;Margin: 0 auto;border-spacing: 0;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;background-color: #F5F5F5;/* width: 100%; */border: 1px solid black;" valign="top" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr style="vertical-align: top;" valign="top">
                <td style="word-break: break-word; vertical-align: top;" valign="top">
                    <div style="background-color:transparent;">
                        <div class="block-grid" style="Margin: 0 auto; min-width: 375px; max-width: 650px; overflow-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word; background-color: #000000;">
                            <div style="border-collapse: collapse;display: table;width: 100%;background-color:#000000;">

                                <div class="col num12" style="min-width: 375px; max-width: 650px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; width: 650px;">
                                    <div style="width:100% !important;">
                                        <div style="border-top:0px solid transparent; border-left:0px solid transparent; border-bottom:0px solid transparent; border-right:0px solid transparent; padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:30px; padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px;">
                                            <div align="center" class="img-container center fixedwidth" style="padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="background-color:transparent;">
                        <!-- START CONTENT ROW -->
                        <div class="block-grid mixed-two-up" style="Margin: 0 auto; min-width: 375px; max-width: 650px; overflow-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word; background-color: #e7f1f8;">
                            <div style="border-collapse: collapse;display: table;width: 100%;background-color:#e7f1f8;">
                                <div class="col num4" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; max-width: 375px; min-width: 216px; width: 216px;">
                                    <div style="width:100% !important;">
                                        <div style="border-top:0px solid transparent; border-left:0px solid transparent; border-bottom:0px solid transparent; border-right:0px solid transparent; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px;">
                                            <div style="color:#555555;font-family:Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:1.2;padding-top:0px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:10px;">
                                                <div style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.2; color: #555555; mso-line-height-alt: 14px;">
                                                    <p style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.2; mso-line-height-alt: 17px; margin: 0;"><strong>PRODUCT:</strong></p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div id="content_con" class="col num8" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; min-width: 375px; max-width: 432px; width: 433px;">
                                    <div style="width:100% !important;">
                                        <div style="border-top:0px solid transparent; border-left:0px solid transparent; border-bottom:0px solid transparent; border-right:0px solid transparent; padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px;">

                                            <div style="color:#555555;font-family:Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:1.2;padding-top:0px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:10px;">
                                                <div style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.2; color: #555555; mso-line-height-alt: 14px;">
                                                    <p style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.2; mso-line-height-alt: 17px; margin: 0;">Test</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you post some code sample...??

Comment: Stackoverflow won't allow me post code saying, my post contains mostly code. Please see the full snippet here - https://www.dropbox.com/s/zvq1mfedw5c6l88/MOBILE%20OFFER.html?dl=0

Comment: I was able to edit and save the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a div-element which gets **100% width** for hyaving class `.col` and **20px padding-left** for having id `#content_con`.
Therefore, it's **100% + 20px wide**.

You can include de padding in the width-calculation by adding **box-sizing**.

```
#content_con {
  padding-left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

---

Your `<meta>`, `<title>`, and `<style>` tags belong inside `<head>` instead of `<body>` by the way!